# How to stop SELECT before INSERT with Django REST Framework

Tags: python, django, postgresql, performance, django-rest-framework

I've used [Django REST Framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) to expose an API which is only used by another service to POST new data. It basically just takes json and inserts it in the DB. That's all.

It's quite a high volume data source (sometimes more than 100 records/second), so I need to tune it a bit.

So I was logging the (PostgreSQL) queries that are run, and I see that every POST gives 3 queries:

```
2019-10-01 11:09:03.320 CEST [23983] postgres@thedb LOG:  statement: SET TIME ZONE 'UTC'
2019-10-01 11:09:03.322 CEST [23983] postgres@thedb LOG:  statement: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "thetable" WHERE "thetable"."id" = 'a7f74e5c-7cad-4983-a909-49857481239b'::uuid  LIMIT 1
2019-10-01 11:09:03.363 CEST [23983] postgres@thedb LOG:  statement: INSERT INTO "thetable" ("id", "version", "timestamp", "sensor", [and 10 more fields...]) VALUES ('a7f74e5c-7cad-4983-a909-49857481239b'::uuid, '1', '2019-10-01T11:09:03.313690+02:00'::timestamptz, 'ABC123', [and 10 more fields...])
```

I tuned the DB for `INSERT`s to be fast, but `SELECT`s are slow. So I would like to remove the SELECT from the system. I added this line to the Serializer:

```
id = serializers.UUIDField(validators=[])
```

But it still does a SELECT. Does anybody know how I can prevent the `SELECT` from happening?

For complete info; the full Serializer now looks like this:

```
import logging
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import TheData

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class TheDataSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = TheData
        fields = [
            'id',
            'version',
            'timestamp',
            'sensor',
            [and 10 more fields...]
        ]


class TheDataDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    id = serializers.UUIDField(validators=[])

    class Meta:
        model = TheData
        fields = '__all__'
```

### Edit

And as requested by frankie567, the `ViewSet`:

```
class TheDataViewSet(DetailSerializerMixin, viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.TheDataSerializer
    serializer_detail_class = serializers.TheDataDetailSerializer

    queryset = TheData.objects.all().order_by('timestamp')

    http_method_names = ['post', 'list', 'get']

    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
    filter_class = TheDataFilter

    pagination_class = TheDataPager

    def get_serializer(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ The incoming data is in the `data` subfield. So I take it from there and put
        those items in root to store it in the DB"""
        request_body = kwargs.get("data")
        if request_body:
            new_request_body = request_body.get("data", {})
            new_request_body["details"] = request_body.get("details", None)
            request_body = new_request_body
            kwargs["data"] = request_body

        serializer_class = self.get_serializer_class()
        kwargs['context'] = self.get_serializer_context()
        return serializer_class(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: The code of the view/viewset would also help :)

Comment: @frankie567 - Good point. I added it to the question. Does that give you any idea?

Answer (score 1):

After some digging, I was able to see where this behaviour comes from. If you look at [Django Rest Framework code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/a7778897adbc7184f1b500bf221c29b2d7201bbd/rest_framework/utils/field_mapping.py#L218-L228):

> ```py
>     if getattr(model_field, 'unique', False):
>         unique_error_message = model_field.error_messages.get('unique', None)
>         if unique_error_message:
>             unique_error_message = unique_error_message % {
>                 'model_name': model_field.model._meta.verbose_name,
>                 'field_label': model_field.verbose_name
>             }
>         validator = UniqueValidator(
>             queryset=model_field.model._default_manager,
>             message=unique_error_message)
>         validator_kwarg.append(validator)
> ```

We see that if `unique` is `True` (which is in your case, as I guess you defined your UUID field as primary key), DRF adds automatically a `UniqueValidator`. This validator performs a `SELECT` request to check if the value doesn't already exist.

It is appended to the ones you are defining in the `validators` parameter of the field, so that's why what you did has no effect.

So, how do we circumvent this?

**First attempt**

```py
class TheDataDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # ... your code

    def get_fields(self):
        fields = super().get_fields()
        fields['id'].validators.pop()
        return fields
```

Basically, we remove the validators of the `id` field after they have been generated. There are surely more clever ways to do this. It seems to me though that DRF may be too opinionated on this matter.

**Second attempt**

```py
class TheDataDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # ... your code

    def build_standard_field(self, field_name, model_field):
        field_class, field_kwargs = super().build_standard_field(field_name, model_field)
        if field_name == 'id':
            field_kwargs['validators'] = []
        return field_class, field_kwargs
```

When generating the field arguments, set an empty `validators` list if we are generating the `id` field.

Comment: I tested this, and unfortunately it doesn't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Or maybe you have tips on how I can debug this?

Comment: Well, that certainly is tinkering. I've updated my answer with another approach.

Comment: Unfortunately that still doesn't work. Any idea from which part the selects are done? Can I somehow print the validators it does just before that?

Comment: Well, maybe I'm horribly wrong. You can try to print the `validators` list to see if there is actually a `UniqueValidator`.

For the select part, you can check the code of `UniqueValidator`: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/validators.py#L74-L80 It does a filter query to check if the object is already existing.

Comment: I put a `print()` in the methods you suggested and I now see that both `get_fields` and `build_standard_field` are never called..

Comment: Oooh, shouldn't it be in `TheDataSerializer` instead? `POST` is not a `detail` route.